# How do I search for images that begin with "xxx-"*.jpg in a given directory?

Tags: php

On my product page I need to display the main image that is stored in the db 'image' field but also the additional images that are in the images folder that begin with the prodid followed by -1, -2 etc

For example:

```
id | name      | image 
1  | product 1 | 1.jpg and also images 1-1.jpg, 1-2.jpg etc
2  | product 2 | 2.jpg and also images 2-1.jpg, 2-2.jpg etc
```

How do I search for images that begin with "prodid-"*.jpg in a given directory?

Comment: what have you searched for and tried and not succeeded?

Comment: you don't ALWAYS know what to search for, especially when english is not your mother tongue. I wasn't aware of the glob function but Jack pointed it out and my question has been covered.

Comment: If you had a pinpoint search knowledge in english, you wouldn't be here. And you know that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: I prefer to get straight to the point and ask the question rather than write half a page of what I did so far that didn't work. If you disagree with that then fine, it's simply your opinion though.

Comment: Ok that's fine by me, but you know, there are people who don't know any programming and don't try to learn, and make their things work by asking people to do it for themselves, and it's not welcome in any programming forum. and BTW I'm not the one downvoted.

Comment: No problem mate, even if you did there would be no offence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`glob`](http://www.php.net/glob):

```
glob($directory . '/' . $prodid . '-*.jpg');
```

Comment: thanks Jack, glob is exactly what I had in mind, just never heard of it before. worked like a charm!

Comment: @bikey77 great! yeah, it's a major simplification for using `opendir` and `readdir` :)

Comment: I'll look into that for future use, usually I have image paths stored in a db but this was a different case.

Answer (score 0):

> On my product page I need to display the main image that is stored in the db 'image' field but also the additional images that are in the images folder that begin with the prodid followed by -1, -2 etc

For searching records that contain a column that starts with '1', you could do the following query:

`SELECT id, name, image FROM yourtable WHERE image LIKE '1-%';`

Comment: they're not in the database, they are only on the filesystem